# Transform reverts image to original position and halt position changes

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, xcode

On xcode I have an imageView wich i want to move to a position and then rotate it... but it wont work... when the transform line is added the imageView reverts back to its original position. After 6 hours staring at the same code i am about to throw in the towel but thought I'd give it one last go...

the code is as follows:

```
fourImageView.center = CGPointMake(80.0f, 108.0f);
twoImageView.center = CGPointMake(80.0f, 108.0f);

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.65f
                      delay:0.5f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^
 {
     fourImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-0.22f);
 } completion:nil];
```

fourImageView and twoImageView are both UIImageViews and declared as (nonatomic, weak) and are linked as outlets to their respective views.

and i have even tried adding to the end:

```
fourImageView.center = CGPointMake(80.0f, 108.0f);
```

but alas no such luk :(

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"nameofAnimation" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
fourImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

this will rotate your image 90°

Comment: works as it should accept if you add a .center argument then it is still not displayed though????:( :( :( :( :(